# Rails Migration Adding uniqueness on text field

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Rails migration into a MySQL database.
I'm simply trying to ensure that the field is unique, and the model isn't sufficing. Do I need to add an index, or is there a way to simply add a uniqueness trait? Can it only be unique for up to so many characters, or is it impossible, in MySQL, to validate uniqueness on a text field?

Answer (score 0):

Specify uniqueness in the model like so:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end
```

[Check here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_index :table_name, [:column_name], :unique => true
```